# System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, .net-5

I am trying to do API call-in.NET 5.0 through the post method but getting System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values. can you please help me with the same?

My code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CommonController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILanguages _Languages;
    public CommonController(ILanguages Languages, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _Languages = Languages;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }


    [HttpGet, Route("GetLanguages")]
    public Languages GetLanguages()
    {
        try
        {
            return _Languages.GetLanguages();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show your request link please and you webAPI routes config(if there are some specific)

Comment: app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

Comment: @demo:http://localhost:5000/api/Common/GetLanguages

Comment: are you doing GET or POST request? Cause your `GetLanguages` action is marked as `POST`

Comment: @demo Actually i want  GET but tried both but same issue

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when converting methods to be async.
Updating the AddControllers function found in Startup.cs worked for me.

Solution here: [ASP.NET CORE, Web API: No route matches the supplied values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459348/asp-net-core-web-api-no-route-matches-the-supplied-values#answer-63834605)

Reason for issue: At runtime the async suffix is removed.

```cs
services.AddControllers(
    options => {
        options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the RoutePrefix attribute at controller level?  The Route attribute at Controller level is used as the fallback route for those actions within the controller that do not have a Route attribute set.  In your case it seems that what you want is to actually use the “api/[controller]” as a prefix for the latter Routes defined at action level.

See more info about RoutePrefix and Route attribute in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2